# How to select all columns from one table, but only selected columns from the other?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to select * from the first table and only x column from the joined table?

```
SELECT *(TABLE1), TABLE2.id, TABLE2.name
  FROM TABLE1
  JOIN TABLE2
ON TABLE1.id_test = TABLE2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

have not tested it but it should look like this:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.id, t2.name
  FROM TABLE1 t1
  JOIN TABLE2 t2
ON t1.id_test = t2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.id, table2.name
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.id_test = table2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
SELECT TABLE1.*, TABLE2.id, TABLE2.name
  FROM TABLE1
  JOIN TABLE2
ON TABLE1.id_test = TABLE2.id
```

though do make sure you really want that * since if you don't want all columns that's a memory waster.